# Cell not display after scroll in collection view - swift 2.1

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

**Main Controller**

```
class MainController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let reUseCellName = "imgCell"

var counter = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}   

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reUseCellName, forIndexPath:indexPath) as! CellClass

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(counter)")
        cell.imgName = counter
        counter++
        return cell
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {       
 let newView = segue.destinationViewController as! showImage
 let cell = sender as! CellClass        
    newView.imgNo = cell.imgName        
}
```

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: Cell doesn't display or image in the cell doesn't display?

Comment: var counter = 1 so image name is "1" use image name as 1.png or 1.jpg

Comment: @anhtu both are not display. only show scroll bar

Comment: @MilanSanathara can you please explain more about "Cell not display after scroll"?

Comment: How @FattiKhan said are you sure your image is called 1 ??

Comment: @FattiKhan thank you , its working

Comment: @MilanSanathara check my answer then . for some ones else help.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the way how your using them, try to define an array with images:

```
var arrayOfImages = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

And use it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` :

```
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: arrayOfImages[indexPath.row])
```

Be sure to connect `DataSoruce` and `Delegate` for collectionView from connection inspector into your view controller to have the data loaded, and be sure to place the right image names.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code . the reason for the image not being displayed is the you have not mentioned the file extension with the image as jpg or png ...  your counter value is "1" so app cannnot load the image name 1 without extension png or jpg 
Use this code :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reUseCellName, forIndexPath:indexPath) as! CellClass

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Complete image name with .png/.jpg")
    cell.imgName = counter
    counter++
    return cell
```

}